# any one can simplify this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

any one can simplify this MYSQL query

same table i want to subtract the sum of values with 1 type to another type

ex: `sum( type1 ) - sum (type 2)`

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(exp_amount) FROM `expenses` WHERE `account_id`  = 1 && `type_id` = 2)
     - (SELECT sum(exp_amount) FROM `expenses` WHERE `account_id`  = 1 && `type_id` = 1) AS balance FROM  `expenses` 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Guide me how to handle this query in Cake php Note : without using this query directly  ->query (...)

Comment: @sandipon - `INTERSECT` would return exactly 0 rows if you included `type_id`.  It's the wrong operation for a number of other reasons.

Comment: This is essentially a [tag:pivot] operation, although I don't know how to do this in cakephp.  `LIMIT` shouldn't be necessary for this statement

Comment: how can i add more than one type_id=2 , 3 sub with type id 1 and 4 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the balance with single scan of the table by using case based aggregation below

```
SELECT Coalesce(sum(CASE WHEN type_id=2 THEN exp_amount END), 0) - Coalesce(sum(CASE WHEN type_id =1 THEN exp_amount END),0) AS balance
FROM expenses
WHERE account_id = 1
  AND type_id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: At minimum, you could/should add the `type_id`s to the `WHERE` clause, in case there are other types.  And probably `COALESCE(...)`, in case there aren't any of a particular type (because `SUM(null)` returns null).

Comment: And then make it a virtual field in cakephp2.x

Comment: Hi radar .. how can i add more than one type_id=2 , 3  sub with type id 1 and 4 ??

Comment: @Subha, add type_id in (2,3) In the case  and add all four type Ids in the where